# Neural net with sinus function: Error does not decrease

Tags: python

I took a Python neural network code from Tariq Rashid for predicting handwritten numbers and tried to adapt it to predict the sinus function. It is working fine with the written numbers. But with the sinus function, the error does not decrease.

My setup for the sinus function is the following:

- NN with 1-10-1 layers with backpropagation.
- input data is 0 until 2*pi.
- target function is the sinus function.
- 2880 input data, shuffled for training purpose. Input data and function data are normalized between [0, 1].
- epochs between 1 and 100
- activation function is sigmoid
- input weights are normal distributed, mean=0, variance is between -0.31 and 0.31 (1/sqr(10) number of hidden neurons)
- learning rate was between 0,00001 and 0,5 (no improvement)

Here you see the error function with the handwriting prediction as it's working fine as it decreases over time:

[image: correct error function]

And here you see the error function of my sinus curve prediction. It just does not decrease. I tried a lot of different setups and I have no clue how I can find the problem.

[image: error function of sinus curve doesn't decrease]

Does anybody have an idea how to locate the error? It took me days, but I have no clue what might be wrong. I saw in examples that with the sigmoid function it should work in principle.

Here comes the code. 
Here is the traingdata: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9xe1wq7b0i9h2y/train-sin-pi-norm_shuffle.csv?dl=0

```
# python notebook for Make Your Own Neural Network  
# original code for a 3-layer neural network, and code for learning the MNIST dataset
# (c) Tariq Rashid, 2016
# license is GPLv2
# code was changed by a random user for learning the sinus function


# numpy provides arrays and useful functions for working with them
import numpy
# scipy.special for the sigmoid function expit()
import scipy.special
import csv   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:

# initialise the neural network
def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
    # set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
    self.inodes = inputnodes
    self.hnodes = hiddennodes
    self.onodes = outputnodes

    # link weight matrices, wih and who
    # weights inside the arrays are w_i_j, where link is from node i to node j in the next layer
    # w11 w21
    # w12 w22 etc 
    self.wih = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
    self.who = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.onodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))

    # learning rate
    self.lr = learningrate

    # activation function is the sigmoid function
    self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

    pass

# train the neural network
def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
    # convert inputs list to 2d array (probably not necessary for the sinus curve model)
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T
    # calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
    # calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
    # output layer error is the (target - actual)
    output_errors = targets - final_outputs

    error_array.append(float(output_errors))

    # hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
    hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

    # update the weights for the links between the hidden and output layers
    self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)), numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))
    # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
    self.wih += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)), numpy.transpose(inputs))     
    pass

# query the neural network
def query(self, inputs_list):

    # convert inputs list to 2d array
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

    # calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)

    # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer       
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    # calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)

    # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

    return final_outputs

# number of input, hidden and output nodes
input_nodes = 1
hidden_nodes = 10
output_nodes = 1
learning_rate = 0.1
error_array = []

# create instance of neural network
n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes, learning_rate)

# load the training data CSV file into a list
training_data_file = open("train-sin-pi-norm_shuffle.csv", 'r')
training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
training_data_file.close()


# train the neural network

# epochs is the number of times the training data set is used for training
epochs =10

for e in range(epochs):

# go through all records in the training data set
for record in training_data_list:
    # split the record by the ';' commas

    all_values = record.split(';')
    inputs = numpy.asfarray(all_values[0])
    targets = float(all_values[1])  
    n.train(inputs, targets)
    pass
pass

# normally here would be the testing of a test data set, but this is not important at the moment.    

plt.plot(error_array, label="Error")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: please post actual code to recreate your problem

Comment: Here's some more information about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks. I added the code and the training data link. Hope it is ok how I did it.

Comment: If there is anything unclear or my explanation is bad, please let me know. I have the feeling that I didn´t fulfill all stackoverflow requirements?!